# Tried save as image to project folder, but error to find a path

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have ASP application that save an image to project folder and save path to MySQL DB, but if I try my code, it say

```
"Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\tree\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Ecommerce_HP\Ecommerce_HP\Foto\"
```

Here is my code

```
if (F1.PostedFile == null || F2.PostedFile == null || F3.PostedFile == null)
        {
            lbleror.Text = "Silahkan Pilih Foto, Minimal 1 Foto";
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                string f1, f2, f3;
                f1 = Path.GetFileName(F1.PostedFile.FileName);
                f2 = Path.GetFileName(F2.PostedFile.FileName);
                f3 = Path.GetFileName(F3.PostedFile.FileName);

                F1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Foto/"+f1));
                F2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Foto/"+f2));
                F3.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Foto/"+f3));

                con.Open();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO databarang(MerkID,NamaBarang,StokBarang,Harga,TanggalBarangMasuk,ImgPath1,ImgPath2,ImgPath3) VALUES(@a,@b,@c,@d,@e,@f,@g,@h)", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a",ddlmerk.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b",txtnama.Value.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c",txtstok.Value.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d",txtharga.Value.Trim());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e",System.DateTime.Now);
                if(f1!=null)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f","Foto/"+f1);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f",null);
                }

                if(f2!=null)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g","Foto/"+f2);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@g",null);
                }

                if(f3!=null)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h","Foto/"+f3);
                }
                else
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@h",null);
                }
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                reset();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                con.Close();
                lbleror.Text = ex.Message.ToString();
                errm.Visible = true;
            }
        }
```

when I try to change

```
F1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Foto/"+f1)); 
to 
F1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Foto/"+f1));
```

the result is same, just could not find a part of the path...
any solution ?

[image: my project structure]

My Project Structure

Comment: The interesting point is the path saved in the parameters. Here we have a Foto root instead of IMG. Are you sure about your paths? Did you check if they exist or not?

Comment: `img` folder should be created before saving files.

Comment: Edited, and still same issue, just change to      "Could not find a part of the path 'c:\users\tree\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\Ecommerce_HP\Ecommerce_HP\Foto\"

Comment: You've shown the Foto folder to be in the Admin folder but that doesn't seem to be in your path.

Answer (score 2):

Your Foto folder is inside the Admin folder. use

```
F1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Admin/Foto/"+f1));
```

instead of

```
F1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Foto/"+f1));
```

Comment: still same issue :(

Answer (score 1):

if you are not inside parent folder. then try to get inside parent folder. by putting (.) before the link. this will take you one step back from your current folder location.

F1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("./img/"+f1));

Comment: you missed /Admin/ Foto

Answer (score 0):

Try the below:

```
F1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Admin/Foto/"+f1));
```